How to set a folder to the path environment variable in Windows 11
There aren't many guides available on adding a folder to the Windows 11 user Path environment variable. This is useful for new programmers to be able to easily run code using command prompt.
An answer on how to do this could be helpful for new developers by allowing them to run utilities directly from the Command Prompt. This removes the need for using the full path, making the process more user-friendly and improving efficiency.

Here is a video tutorial I created that shows how to set a folder to the path environmental variable in Windows 11.
Alternatively, below is a step-by-step description of the process with screenshots.
As an example, I'll be adding C:\Users\SomeApp, because I want to be able to start example.exe located in C:\Users\SomeApp\example.exe.
On the lower middle section of your screen where it says "Search", type "control panel" and navigate to your Control Panel.

The window that pops up is the Control Panel. Click "System and Security" at the top left-hand side of this window.

In the next window, select System.

In the middle of the next screen, select Advanced system settings

On the panel that pops up, click "Environmental Variables..."
On the next panel, select Path and then Edit...

On the panel that pops up, select New.

This is where we will put the path. In my case, I will type: C:\Users\SomeApp as shown below.

Select "Ok" on all three open panels and restart command prompt and you'll be good to go!

You can skip those first steps by just hitting the Start button/key and typing "advanced system", then picking the "View advanced system settings" item that results.

You can use a command to append your path value to the PATH variable - mind the semicolon after %PATH% and before the path you're adding:
set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\SomeApp"

Verify with
echo %PATH%

Then you should be able to run commands from C:\Users\SomeApp.
This will only apply to the current command window!
To make the change permanent, you can use setx instead - the caveat is that the current command window is not affected by this, so you will still need to set as well if you intend to use the current command window to run more commands - it is not necessary if you just want to run the command once to add the path for all later usage.
Please note that using setx has many pitfalls and caveats and you are probably best off using the GUI method outlined in the other answer.
Among the problems is the fact that %PATH% will contain both the contents of the machine-wide ("All Users") value as well as the user-specific value - and you will now overwrite the user-specific value with that.
Another issue is that if any of the paths contain an environment variable (for example, some application defines %MYAPPINSTALLDIR% and then adds %MYAPPINSTALLDIR%\bin\current to %PATH%), those will be expanded on the fly and the expanded values will be written, with possibly very annoying side effects.
To make the change for all users, the /m switch will also need to be used, but consider the above very strongly - this method may be useful for other environment variables, but %PATH% has enough peculiarities to tread carefully.
For what it's worth, adding a registry key (this can also be done by a command) might be a safer bet, as that's how those variables are actually stored.

Sure, but you should mention that this will only make the change to PATH in the current console session. Other apps won't see the change.

I kinda forgot about that, you need SETX to make it stick (but that one won't affect current session so you use both if you want to use the same shell to run commands right away)

@CareyGregory I read up on the docs again as it's been a while since I've last been doing this, and it's even worse - I let the answer stand but added more information on why you probably don't want to do this (except for the temporary version, maybe)
